# Is there a verb opposite of "to exist"?

Tags: verbs, antonyms

I can say that something exists or that is does not exist. Should there not be some way to express the opposite of the verb "to exist" as a substitution? Or can something the doesn't exist be allowed to have a positive verb at all? Or do verbs ever only have one opposite? "not sit" could be "stand" or "lie", so that wouldn't, but "not breathe" seems to be "suffocate" and maybe not anything else.

Comment: If something doesn't "exist" (even in your febrile imagination) then how could you even think of "it" actually *doing* anything? A physical thing that *ceases* to exist could be said to ***dematerialize***, after which it isn't "there" to "do" anything at all (except maybe [***rematerialize***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rematerialize)). But if it never existed at all? Also - forget the idea that every word has an "opposite". It's not reflective of *most* use of language.

Comment: I'm not aware of any word that could substitute *exist*, but I think there is a good explanation why. If you talk about something that does not exist, you want to stress its existence and negating it.

Comment: sure, but you may say, "it is existent" or "it is nonexistent", so why not be able to say "it exists" or "it ____"?

Comment: To be or not to be – that is the question.

Comment: My answer is therefore *not to be*. :-)

Comment: I was wondering about it too, I heard on a tv show called "the young pope" Where it was said "there is absence in presence" which led me to this page, looking for an answer to the opposite of existence.

Answer (score 4):

there are many words:[**Nonexistent**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/nonexistent?q=Nonexistent), it was **Imagined** or be **[Imaginary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/imaginary)**, it could be a **[hallucination](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/hallucination#hallucination__2)** or be **hallucinatory**, **[fictional](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/fictional)** or [**fictitious**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/fictitious), **[illusory](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/illusory#illusory__2)**, **[fanciful](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/fanciful)**.

I could go on, but the links have synonyms too.

Comment: I'm wondering about verb forms of it rather than adjectives.

Comment: imagine, halucinate, fictionalize, archaicly there is also fancy. there are verb forms for virtually all the words I gave you if you would look.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/fancy

Comment: I think we are looking for an intransitive verb.

Comment: In that case I am running into a wall here. My linguistic/ideological background is keeping me from constructing a sentence or senario where such a word would ever be used.

Comment: The opposite to "to exist" would be useful where something does not exist *in relation to* something else, e.g. "footnotes do not exist on this document", or "a balcony that does not exist saves money" or "it is possible that a motive for the crime does not exist".  Also, in software, things do not exist all the time! For instance, a cell in a spreadsheet may or may not have a value - in the case that it does not, the value does not *exists*.

Comment: I want a word for this sentence to describe my childless sister:
"My children exist. My sister's children inexist." 
That is, she's never had children, or even considered having children. Or perhaps, her children are dead.