# What is a word that describes something that (potentially) never existed?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that has a similar meaning to (potentially) "never-existent"?

For example:

> "John claimed that the potentially never-existent journal was 'lost'."

Comment: Not currently existing but existed at some point vs. never have existed at all? Fictitious?

Comment: @Diafotismos, I edited the question to prefix _potentially_ to _never-exsitent_ based on the example that you gave.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a verb opposite of "to exist"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/265022/is-there-a-verb-opposite-of-to-exist)

Comment: "Mythical" is often used in such situations.  Depends on how much chance there is that the journal ever existed in the first place.  ("Alleged" is good if there is a (small) chance that it existed.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "***alleged***" to mean "claimed but not proven (to exist)".

> "John claimed that the ***alleged*** journal was 'lost'."

ODO:

> **[alleged](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/alleged)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> [attributive] *Said, without proof, to have taken place or to have a
>   specified illegal or undesirable quality*:
>   ‘the alleged
>   conspirators’
>
> ‘The British Museum, too, says it knows nothing about any alleged
>   fakes in its displays.’

Answer (score 2):

1. [Imaginary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/imaginary): Existing only in the imagination or fancy

***Example***: He blames the hold-up on an [imaginary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/imaginary) broker he calls

2. [Illusory](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/illusory):Causing illusion; misleading

***Example***:In the end, though, the size of the field staff, the number of offices, and the number of early voters might be [illusory](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/illusory).

3. [Supposed](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/supposed): Generally assumed or believed to be the case, but not necessarily so.

***Example***: Vietnam is the supposed site of an ancient temple

4. [Hypothetical](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hypothetical): Imagined or suggested.

***Example***: This is all very [hypothetical](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hypothetical) but supposing Jackie got the job, how would that affect you?

Answer (score 1):

This question is similar to *[A word to describe an incident or event that may or may not have taken place](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/311933/a-word-to-describe-an-incident-or-event-that-may-or-may-not-have-taken-place)*.

My answer, at least, is the same:

> [***purported***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/purported) - said to be true or real but not definitely true or real

(From *Merriam-Webster*)

If you were to say, "purported journal," the connotation would be that you are quite skeptical.